# How can I make text on tree plot legible

Tags: r

Is there any way to change the text that is displayed for tree items during a plot so that it is more legible? If possible, I would like to insert my own titles at plotting time, but I cant find a way to do this.

```
library(tree)

tr = tree(model, data=file_as_table)
summary(tr)
png(filename="test_tree_minecraft.png")
plot(tr)
text(tr)
dev.off()
```

Here is the image I get when I run the above code: [here](http://postimg.org/image/8p4ckb731/)

Comment: there are very many things you can pass to `?text` and/or `?par`. have you tried any of those?

Comment: I have never seen them used. Im still relatively new to R so I didnt know they existed. Can you link an example?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by more legible. a reproducible example or image would be very helpful. you can do lots of things, for example, the example under `?tree::tree` can be modified: `plot(cpus.ltr);  text(cpus.ltr, cex = .8, srt = 45, col = 1:5)`

Comment: Those modifications to `text()` are a giant improvement on what I had. Thanks! Any chance there is a way to specify names in the plot directly?

Comment: the variables? you could but it would be easier just to name them how you want before creating the tree

Comment: Unfortunately that is impractical for me since a lot of (bad) code rests on the existing (long) variable names.